# Extracting non-null portion of pandas series from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, series, notnull

Say I have this DataFrame:

```
    C1    C2    C3
0    1   4.4    99
1    2   4.5   200
2    3   NaN    65
3    4   3.2   140
```

I want to extract only the column (series) C2 and only the non-null elements of that series.

I can do that in two steps:

```
d = df.loc[df['C2'].notnull()]
s=d['C2']
```

s will be

```
0    4.4
1    4.5
3    3.2
```

Can I do this in one step?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about `dropna`

```
df.C2.dropna()
Out[486]: 
0    4.4
1    4.5
3    3.2
Name: C2, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `query` with `.notna` if you want to filter your dataframe:

```
df.query('C2.notna()')
```

**Output**

```
   C1   C2   C3
0   1  4.4   99
1   2  4.5  200
3   4  3.2  140
```

Answer (score 0):

you can combine your two steps into one as well and drop the loc

```
df[df['C2'].notnull()]['C2']
```

Comment: Better: `df.loc[df['C2'].notnull(), 'C2']`

Comment: can you explain how this is better?

Comment: Have a [read](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)